# Consume API to Get token in Angular with a proxy

Tags: angular, proxy

I have a question. If I have an API already published on a website, for example, https://myapp.functions/Service/api/getToken, and this function returns a JSON with a token like "12jd3..," how can I consume this request from my Angular application? To access the API, I had to configure a proxy.conf.json file as follows:"

```json
{
 "/Service/api/*":{
   "target": "https://myapp.funtions",
   "secure": false,
   "changeOrigin":true
 } 
}
```

The request should be made using a POST method and should receive the username and password in the body. I'm not sure if it's necessary to include a header with information. What should I add to this code?

```
 const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': '*/*'
    });
    const options = { headers: headers };

    const body = {
      id: 'user',
      password: '123'
    };

    return this.http.post(‘Service/api/getToken’, body, options)
      .subscribe((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use `return` so you don't need to subscribe the http request. Exapmle:

#### Your Service

```
login() {
    const body = {
      id: 'user',
      password: '123'
    };

    return this.http.post('Service/api/getToken', body);
}
```

#### Any component

```
constructor(private readonly myService: MyService) {}

login() {
  this.myService.login().subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
      console.log(data); // Here is your token
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err); // Handle error
    }

})
}
```

And right: httpClient knows that you send json. So in your case you don't need to set a header.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you know how I can configure the proxy to work in production,  when my website is deployed? It's said that this can often cause problems when the site is in production.

Comment: I can show you a sample tomorrow how we do it in our system

Comment: In our package.json we set the config (like yours) so: `"dev:app-hub": "ng serve app-hub --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host=0.0.0.0 --port ${APP_FRONTEND_DEV_PORT_HUB:-13106}",` and in production we don't use the proxy.